# How to resize the datagridview on button click?

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

How can I change the Height and Width of the datagridview when clicking on a button.

```
private void btnResize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void btnResize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.Height = //set an int  desired height;
  dataGridView1.Width = //set an int desired Width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
    dataGrid.Size = new Size(100, 200);

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the smarter way. The better way if it is WPF the use blend behaviour , `ChangePropertyAction` and use Button Click as trigger. You can add more than one `ChangeProeprtyAction` if you want to set more than one property.

WPF example

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=button}">
    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Height" Value="20"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

DataTrigger if you want to change it based on some property value otherwise you can change it to